# dojo looking for build.js in wrong path

Tags: dojo

I am trying to run my dojo project on a local Tomcat (7.0) server using Eclipse Juno 64bit as a dev environment.

I ran into a problem yesterday concerning how dojo assumes where files are stored within the source tree.

Below is a firebug log showing the issue:

```
304 Not Modified 23ms dojo.js (Line 295)
GET http://localhost:8080/src/dojo-18/dojo/parser.js

304 Not Modified 46ms dojo.js (Line 295)
GET http://localhost:8080/src/dojo-18/dojo/util.js

404 Not Found 24ms dojo.js (Line 295)
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/src/dojo-18/dojo/util.js"
```

The first 2 paths (and a lot before them) are loaded correctly, now the third path is incorrect, there is no util.js in the base dojo folder, I dont know why dojo would look there.

In order to solve the issue I tried describing the path better using the baseUrl property

```html
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        isDebug: true,
        parseOnLoad: false,
        baseUrl: './src/dojo-18/',
    };
</script>
```

the dojo.js is referenced like this:

```html
<script src="./src/dojo-18/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show the code which references util.js ? If it is a module you define yourself you should use packages to define where the loader should look for it. Check the packages section here: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dojo_config/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo does not look for `util.js` by itself, if it's doing that, you have imported a module called **util** by yourself, for example:

```js
require([ "dojo/util" ], function(util) {
    // This will not work because the util module does not exist
});
```

If you want to reference a self defined module, you have to configure the package first using `dojoConfig`:

```html
<script>
    dojoConfig = {
        isDebug: true,
        parseOnLoad: false,
        baseUrl: './src/dojo-18/',
        packages: [{
            name: 'custom',
            location: '/path/to/custom'
        }]
    };
</script>
```

Then you can reference a module in that package by using:

```js
require([ "custom/util" ], function(util) {
    // This will load the custom util module
});
```

In this case, the Dojo AMD loader will look for `util.js` inside the `/path/to/custom` folder, so it would become:

```
/path/to/custom/util.js
```